# Solution of Heat Equation converges in 2-norm

Tags: fourier-analysis, heat-equation

consider the heat equation on a circle $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ with initial data $f(x)$ integrable on $[0,1]$.

Let $u(x,t)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_ne^{-4n^2\pi^2t}e^{2\pi in x}$, where $a_n$ is the fourier coefficient of $f$. I know $u(x,t)$ solve the heat equation.

I am trying to show that $||u(x,t)-f||_2\to 0$ as $t\to 0$. I try to use the Parseval's identity since here we have the information of fourier coefficients and I got $||u(x,t)-f||_2=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}|a_n(e^{-4\pi ^2n^2t}-1)|^2$. I am trying to estimate $e^{-4\pi ^2n^2t}-1$ and I guess it is impossible to get $\sigma>0$ such that $|e^{-4\pi^2n^2 t}-1|<\epsilon$ for all $|t|<\sigma$ independent of $n$, if we can get such $\sigma$, then the problem will be settled. Any suggestions?

Comment: If $f$ is not square integrable, you won't be able to show this because it's wrong. If $f$ is square integrable, then its Fourier coefficients are square summable and the desired convergence follows from the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @MaoWao Could you elaborate "the desired convergence follows from the dominated convergence theorem"?

Comment: The summands are bounded by $\lvert a_n\rvert^2$ and converge to zero as $t\to 0$ (strictly speaking, you have to apply this to every null sequence $(t_k)$). Btw, there's a typo in a couple of places, it should always be $e^{-4\pi^2 n^2 t}$.

Comment: @MaoWao I know each term converges to $0$ as $t\to 0$, but they converges to 0 in different speed as $t\to 0$ right? Why is the whole infinite sum go to $0$?

Comment: So you are not familiar with the dominated convergence theorem then?

Comment: @MaoWao I am sorry. I only know the dominated convergence theorem for Lesbegue integral, I guess it can be applied to prove this. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean. Remember that the sum $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty b_n$ is the same as the Lebesgue integral of the function $n\mapsto b_n$ with respect to the counting measure on $\mathbb Z$ (if the $b_n$ are positive are absolutely summable).

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
     u(x,t)-u(x,0) &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n(e^{-4n^2\pi^2 t}-1)e^{2\pi inx} \\
    \int_{0}^{1}|u(x,t)-u(x,0)|^2dx &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|a_n|^2|e^{-4n^2\pi^2 t}-1|^2
\end{align}
The above tends to $0$ as $t\downarrow 0$ by the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence applied to the last sum on the right.